# Gnome 3 Overview Delay

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3

I recently switched to Ubuntu Gnome in preparation of the eventual official switch. Overall I actually really like it and have been using it fine for a few months. However, something that has been bothering me is the delay when going to the "overview" screen (with the list of applications open). I often hit the super key and start typing an application name in order to open stuff, and the "delay" causes my typing and opening to lag.

I was wondering if there is a setting I can change to make the overview open immediately once the super key is pressed. I know my system is not lagging since I am using a 2016 Dell ultrabook.

Answer (score 1):

Try [impatience](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/) addon which lets you adjust Gnome animation speed. It might be already in your package manager [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-shell-extension-impatience&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) as `gnome-shell-extension-impatience`.